# ASP.NET - Link in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I created page with GridView, but I need to make links in 1 column, if I try to put `<a>` tag it doesn't work, it just shows plain html `<a>` tag.

I need at first row link to otherpage.aspx?id=1, second row otherpage.aspx?id=2 and so on.

Grid.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" CellPadding="4"
  ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" PageSize="5" ViewStateMode="Enabled"
  Width="100%" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1">

    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

    <Columns>
    </Columns>


</asp:GridView>
```

Grid.aspx.cs

```
DataTable data = new DataTable();

data.Columns.Add("New column");
// others columns


for (int i = 1;i < 10; i++)
{
    data.Rows.Add();
    data.Rows[i]["New column"] = "<a href='otherpage.aspx?id='"+ i +">Link</a>";
    // other columns
}

GridView1.DataSource = data;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Or is any better solution to create links in GridView (programmatically)?

Comment: But i dont know how to implement it directly into my code (for loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding a new column in the DataTable, you can add a TemplateField to your GridView and put a HyperLink control in it. The Hyperlink control renders as an `a` tag in HTML.

Using the TemplateField has the advantage that you do not have to create controls dynamically (which sometimes is not the most stable approach). For more details on the TemplateField see this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479353.aspx).

### ASPX

For your requirements, you can set the properties of the HyperLink control directly in the ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gdv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gdv_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="lnk" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Text") %>'
                    NavigateUrl='<%# "otherpage.aspx?id=" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id").ToString() %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

### ASPX and Code Behind for a more complex scenario

For a more complex scenario, you can set the properties in Code Behind:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gdv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gdv_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="lnk" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

protected void gdv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var lnk = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("lnk");
        lnk.NavigateUrl = "otherpage.aspx?id=" + ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["Id"].ToString();
        lnk.Text = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["Text"].ToString();
    }
}
```

In the `RowDataBound` event, the HyperLink control in the TemplateField is identified and the `Text` and `NavigateUrl` properties are set.

Comment: Without template it is not possible? Is possible to put html tags into gridview?

Comment: @Tomsk The template is the stable way to put custom HTML tags into a GridView cell. I used a HyperLink control to display the link. It renders as an `a` tag, but can be set easily from ASP.NET. I've updated the answer with a simpler approach that does not need a `RowDataBound` event handler in Code Behind.

Comment: Im getting: Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLinkField' does not have a public property named 'ID'... Is not easier way to put html tags into GridView? What about if I need in  1 column two links with custom class etc?

Comment: @Tomsk The error message points in the direction that you took a HyperLinkField instead of a HyperLink control. The TemplateField is built for adding custom HTML into a GridView cell. So I'd still propose to use it, even if you decide to put regular HTML into it instead of ASP.NET controls later on. For starters, I'd try it with a TemplateField with a HyperLink control in it. I've updated my answer and added a link to an overview of how to use the TemplateField.

Answer (score 2):

You can use code like this:

```
foreach (GridViewRow gr in gv.Rows)
{
    HyperLink hp = new HyperLink();
    hp.Text = gr.Cells[0].Text;
    hp.NavigateUrl = "~/Default.aspx?name=" + hp.Text;
    gr.Cells[0].Controls.Add(hp);
}
```

For more samples you can see this link [create links in dynamically created grid view](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/480297/createpluslinksplusinplusdynamicallypluscreatedplu)

Comment: But how to add link directly in my for loop? I dont want to have 2 for loops